# Finding 2 straight line tangent to y=(x^2)/(x-1)

Tags: calculus

Find 2 straight line that are tangent to y=(x^2)/(x-1) and pass through the point (2,0)

What I've done so far is take the derivative of the function y'= (x^2-2x)/(x-1).
I tried plugging in x=2, y'(2) but end up getting 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First, find the equation for the tangent line to $y=f(x)=x^2/(x-1)$ at a specific point $(a,a^2/(a-1))$ using the point-slope formula and the derivative at $x=a$ to get the slope. Now your equation for the tangent line is
$$y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a).$$
In this, put $x=2,y=0$ and proceed to solve for $a$ (the only unknown remaining). Hopefully there are two possible $a$ and you can go backward and get the equations sought.

Comment: Do I substitute a as x?

Comment: The $f(a),\ f'(a)$ in the displayed formula for the tangent line are obtained by substituting $a$ for $x$ in the formulas for $f(x), f'(x).$ The point is one needs to do this if using $x,y$ as the variables to descdribe the tangent line. Your initial point $(2,0)$ is *not* on the given curve, and the tangent lines from that to the curve meet the curve at point(s) as yet unknown.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you!

Comment: One of the tangent lines is the $x$ axis. I think for the other one $a=4/3$ in above...